# Tramp keeps opening the connection

Tags: tramp

Once I connect to a remote computer using tramp. It connects but tramp keeps trying to open the connection.  This is the output that is printed again and again.

```
 Tramp: Waiting for prompts from remote shell...done
 Tramp: Found remote shell prompt on ‘gnu’
 Tramp: Opening connection for gnu using ssh...done
 Tramp: Opening connection for gnu using ssh...
 Tramp: Sending command ‘exec ssh -q   -o ControlMaster=auto -o   
 ControlPath='tramp.%C' -o ControlPersist=no -e none gnu’
```

I don't know what's is wrong exactly. Any ideas?

**Edit**
The problem was not really resolved. I looked into `recenf` as suggested by @MichaelAlbinus. I default recenf but nothing more. My rencenf config is below

`(require 'recentf)
(setq recentf-auto-cleanup 'never) ;; disable before we start recentf!
(recentf-mode 1)`

For now I'm getting away with `C-g`  until it stop trying to connect.

Then I defined this function when I lose patience.

`(defun tramp-refresh ()
  (interactive)
  (recentf-cleanup)
  (tramp-cleanup-all-buffers)
  (tramp-cleanup-all-connections))`

Comment: Have you tried `tramp-cleanup-all-buffers` or `tramp-cleanup-all-connections`? If you want to poke around a bit before, `tramp-list-connections` could be a starting point.

Comment: Do you use `recentf`? It remembers old connections.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Somehow I didn't see your comments. I don't use `recentf` and `tramp-clean-up-all-connection` is useful. I guess the problem was with the `ssh-agent` on the local host.  It's working fine now. Thanks.

Comment: @DJJ: care to elaborate on the problem with `ssh-agent`? Thanks

Comment: @runejuhl. I provided more info in the post.  I'll try to post more info when the problem shows up again. :-).